# Who codified/how was it codified that oxidation is electron loss and reduction is electron gain (OILRIG)?

Tags: redox, oxidation-state, history-of-chemistry

As far as I can tell from some reading on the subject, the terms oxidation and reduction were first used by Antoine Lavoisier and contemporaries to discuss combustion in the late 1700s. The term electron wasn't coined for another 100 years, so I'm wondering who came up with/proved the above concept, commonly codified as "OILRIG".

Comment: https://www.britannica.com/science/oxidation-reduction-reaction/Historical-origins-of-the-redox-concept will be of interest

Comment: As you state, in early chemistry, oxidation meant combining with oxygen, e.g., burning, and reduction meant removing oxygen from an ore, e.g., reducing iron oxides to metal.

Comment: Oxidation/reduction *may be* the lose/gain of electrons, but need not to. More general is increase/decrease of the oxidation state/number, what is the formal charge after heterolytic bond breaking according electronegativities of atoms. //  Note that electrolysis as the link between charge and oxidation/reduction is known about 100 years longer than an electron too. // The question is more suited for [History of Science and Mathematics SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com). I have never heard about "OILRIG", even if it is clear what it means.

Comment: i agree its more complicated than this rule of thumb poutnik. i found the mnemonic here though it is well known https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redox#/media/File:Redox_example.svg